How to handle this error: "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items') Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor"
I'm writing code in N-tier architecture in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. But I'm getting an error while I'm passing data from view to view model and from view model to controller. Actually view model is returned as null.
When I click the submit button, this error occurs. The view model didn't get any data from the view.
Here is the exception details:

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues, string dataGroupField)

This is the view model:
public class ProductInfoViewModel
{
    public ProductInfoViewModel()
    {
        this.RawProductVariants = new List<RawProductVariant>();
        this.FinishedProductVariants = new List<FinishedProductVariant>();
    }

    [Key]
    //have to specify Product ID
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name can not be null")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; } = default!;

    [ForeignKey("Brand")]
    [Display(Name = "Brand")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Brand")]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HSCodeInfo")]
    [Display(Name = "HS Code")]
    public int HSCodeId { get; set; } = default!;

    [ForeignKey("ProductCategory")]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Brand? Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual HSCodeInfo? HSCodeInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory? ProductCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RawProductVariant> RawProductVariants { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FinishedProductVariant> FinishedProductVariants { get; set; }
}

This is controller:
public class ProductInfoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ProductInfoService _productInfoService;
    private readonly HSCodeService _hscodeService;
    private readonly ProductCategoryService _productCategoryService;
    private readonly BrandService _brandService;

    public ProductInfoController(IProductInfoRepository productInfoRepository, IHScodeRepository hscodeRepository,
        IProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository, IBrandRepository brandRepository)
    {
        _productInfoService = new ProductInfoService(productInfoRepository);
        _hscodeService = new HSCodeService(hscodeRepository);
        _productCategoryService = new ProductCategoryService(productCategoryRepository);
        _brandService = new BrandService(brandRepository);
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.hs = _hscodeService.GetAllHSCode();
        ViewBag.category = _productCategoryService.GetAllProductCategory();
        ViewBag.brand = _brandService.GetBrandList();
        return View(_productInfoService.GetAllProductInfo());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(SearchProductInfoViewModel spvm)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.hs = _hscodeService.GetAllHSCode();
        ViewBag.category = _productCategoryService.GetAllProductCategory();
        ViewBag.brand = _brandService.GetBrandList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(ProductInfoViewModel pvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string status = _productInfoService.AddNewProductInfo(pvm);

            if (status == "OK")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(pvm);
    }
}

This is the Create view:
@model DL.ViewModels.Inventory.ProductInfoViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row  justify-content-between gap-3 mb-4">
    <div class="">
        <h4 class="text_primary fw-bold">Add Product</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <a asp-action="ProductList" asp-controller="Inventory"
           title="Sale Order List"
           class="my_button px-2 py-1 ">
            Product List
        </a>

    </div>
</div>

<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="ProductInfo" method="post">
    <div class="sale_order_container rounded-2 mb-4">
        <div class="">
            <h6 class="border-bottom border-secondary-subtle soc_title py-3 px-4">
                Product Information
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4">

            <div class="grid_cols_2 ">

                <div class="">
                    <label for="ProductArticle" asp-for="ProductName" class="form-label text-secondary"></label>
                    <input type="text"
                           asp-for="ProductName"
                           name="ProductArticle"
                           id="ProductArticle"
                           class="form-control shadow-none rounded-0" />
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <label for="ProductArticle" asp-for="BrandId" class="form-label text-secondary"></label>
                    <select name="Brand"
                            asp-for="BrandId"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.brand, "Id","BrandName"))"
                            id="Brand"
                            class="form-select shadow-none rounded-0">
                        <option value="" selected>Select Brand</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="BrandId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <label for="ProductArticle" asp-for="HSCodeId" class="form-label text-secondary"></label>
                    <select name="HSCode"
                            asp-for="HSCodeId"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.hs, "Id","HSCODE"))"
                            id="hscode"
                            class="form-select shadow-none rounded-0">
                        <option value="" selected>Select HS Code</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="HSCodeId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <label for="ProductArticle" asp-for="CategoryId" class="form-label text-secondary"></label>
                    <select name="Category"
                            asp-for="CategoryId"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.category, "Id","CategoryName"))"
                            id="Category"
                            class="form-select shadow-none rounded-0">
                        <option value="" selected>Select Category</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 m-auto">
                <button class="sol_add_button w-100 ">
                    <i role="button"
                       class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk fa-fw fw-bolder fs-5"></i>
                    <span>Save</span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#left_inventory_menu").show();
    </script>
}


When you call return View()  or RedirectToAction() you should be sure that every object used in the view is properly initialized. The HTTP Post to create method redirects to the Index view without initializing the elements as you do in the HTTP GET of the Index view
